# Showing a set is open.

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been given a question - with most of which I'm pretty confident - and to make my solution work I have to show that the set $$H = \left\{z \in \mathbb{C} | \exists x,y\in\mathbb{R} \text{ with } x\notin [0,1]\text{ such that } z = x+iy  \right\} \cup \left\{z \in \mathbb{C} | \exists x,y\in\mathbb{R} \text{ with } y\notin [0,1]\text{ such that } z = x+iy  \right\}$$
is open. I just need to show that each of the sets in the union is open which automatically will show that $H$ is open but I've hit a bit of a dead end and don't know where to go from here.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: recall that the complex plane is in fact isomorphic to a two dimensional real space, then what would be the topology on the complex plane? More precisely, what would be the "opens sets" on the complex plane?

Comment: @Muduri_Ousin I've managed to do it now but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Each set is the complement of a closed strip in $\mathbb C$.  The first one is the complement of the closed vertical strip $\{z=x+iy\mid x\in [0,1]\}$.  Hence open.   Similarly the other is the complement of a  closed horizontal strip.

For instance,  the strips are homeomorphic to $\mathbb R×[0,1]\subset \mathbb R^2$, hence closed.

Comment: I was looking for a more in depth solution which I've now managed to figure out. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$H=C/[0,1]\times[0,1]$ so open